# twitter bootstrap alignment elements center

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a panle body that including an image and button under it.

[image]

```
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/70x50" class="img-thumbnail img-radio">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-radio  btn-xs">img-1</button>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="left-item" class="hidden">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/70x50" class="img-thumbnail img-radio">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-radio  btn-xs">img-2</button>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="middle-item" class="hidden">
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
```

I could not set alignment of button and image. Button should be under image and center. I could create a temporary solution with custom css but I want to learn is there a solution with bootstrap.

Comment: Try with `text-center` class on your `col-md-6`?

Answer (score 2):

Since the labels are of `inline` display in nature, the class `text-center` does the trick for you!

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/70x50" class="img-thumbnail img-radio">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-radio  btn-xs">img-1</button>
            <input type="checkbox" id="left-item" class="hidden">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/70x50" class="img-thumbnail img-radio">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-radio  btn-xs">img-2</button>
            <input type="checkbox" id="middle-item" class="hidden">
        </div>
    </div>
```

#### Preview

[image]

#### Fiddle: http://www.bootply.com/QwYES83I3B

Comment: Yes i saw ! but in the mobile view its changes

Comment: @Jake745 Obviously, the mobile view has its own limitations. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

## [DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/IUzidMCMtm)

```
<div class="panel-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/70x50" class="img-thumbnail img-radio" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-radio  btn-xs">img-1</button>

                        <input type="checkbox" id="left-item" class="hidden" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/70x50" class="img-thumbnail img-radio" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-radio  btn-xs">img-2</button>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="middle-item" class="hidden" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Why are you duplicating `col-md-12`? Is there any reason?

Comment: because `col-md-12` takes the full width of the screen and easy to `center-align`  the content , it works in all types of screen